# Convert Json to svg

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I need help in converting json to svg. I have file json and I have to decode it and after that I'll have div container and then I need convert result to svg. I haven't any ideas how to do it,please help me who can))) Thanks a lot)) Preferably JavaScript)

JSON:

```
{"pages":
    [
        {"id":"page1","class":"art active","type":"box","objHtml":
            {"width":"380px","width_page":380,"height":"380px","left":"770px","fon_color":"transparent"},
            "boxes":[{"id":"box1","type":"style","objHtml":{},"insideBox":"","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                {"id":"box2","type":"figure","objHtml":
                    {"zIndex":"2","height":"160px","top":"60px","left":"110px","fon_color":"transparent","border_width":0,"width":"160px","width_page":160,"svg_fon":"#f44336","svg_border_width":"0","svg_border_color":"#000000","svg_gradient":false,"svg_image":false},
                    "insideBox":"<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?-->\n<!-- Round  -->\n<svg viewBox=\"0 0 200 200\" xmlns=\"https://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:svg=\"https://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"160\"><defs></defs>\n\t\t<g stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#f44336\">\n\t\t\t<circle cx=\"100\" cy=\"100\" r=\"94\"></circle>\n\t\t</g>\n</svg>\n","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box3","type":"line","objHtml":{"line_width":6,"line_color":"#000000","line_style":"solid","zIndex":"7","height":"auto","top":"110px","left":"-53px","rotate":15,"width":"285px","width_page":285},"insideBox":"<hr style=\"border-top: 6px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; height: 0px;\">","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box4","type":"line","objHtml":{"line_width":6,"line_color":"#000000","line_style":"solid","zIndex":"1","height":"auto","width":"342px","width_page":342,"top":"75px","left":"-44px","rotate":20},"insideBox":"<hr style=\"border-top: 6px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; height: 0px;\">","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box5","type":"text","objHtml":{"zIndex":"8","height":"auto","width":"360px","width_page":360,"top":"200px","left":"10px","letterSpacing":"7px"},"insideBox":"<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size: 100px; font-weight: 600; color: rgb(33, 33, 33); font-family: \"Didact Gothic\";\">СУШИ</span></p>","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box6","type":"text","objHtml":{"zIndex":"9","height":"auto","width":"360px","width_page":360,"top":"310px","left":"10px"},"insideBox":"<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-family: \"Didact Gothic\";\">Ресторан японской и паназиатской кухни</span></p>","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""}]}]}
```

Comment: Write a compiler: https://medium.com/@kosamari/how-to-be-a-compiler-make-a-compiler-with-javascript-4a8a13d473b4

Comment: Do you already loaded the JSON do you have a response?

Comment: No) I need this json decode to html and result code convert to svg) So, I need json convert to svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. Let mi know if this is what you need.

I've putted your JSON in `svg.json` in the same folder as the `index.html`

#### index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
<!--a div were to put the SVG-->
<div id="svgWrap"></div> 
  
<script>
// a function to load the json
  function loadJSON(URL, callback) {

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET',URL, true); 
  
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}
  
  // call the loadJSON
  loadJSON('svg.json', useJSON);  
  
  function useJSON(response){
  //you have the json, use it!
    let json = JSON.parse(response);
  //put the svg inside the divWrap
    svgWrap.innerHTML = json.pages[0].boxes[1].insideBox;
  }


  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```